# Jetpack Compose Canvas not accurate

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am having an issue with jetpack compose canvas when using `@Preview`, I would like to display all the content to fill the canvas in the preview but it doesn't currently.

[image]

I am setting `375dp` width and then a Rect with `375f`, I understand that `dp` is different than just `float`, but how can I set the width so the green rect fills the canvas without using `canvas.width` for example as the rect width?

Comment: Please don't upload code images. Use formatted code instead, more info [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). I will take back my downvote if you edit the question.

Answer (score 1):

When drawing on `Canvas` you're operating with pixels, not `Dp`. `onDraw` is called on `DrawScope`, and it has `size` property which is already converted to pixels:

```
Canvas(Modifier) {
    drawRect(color = Color.Green, size = size)
}
```

Also `DrawScope` is inherited from `Density`, so you can convert any `Dp` to pixels with `375.toDp()`.